# Typescript or JS class extension

Tags: typescript, extension-methods, mixins

Let's say I want class `Warrior` in my game. And my warriors can only walk.

```
class Warrior{

constructor(){}

walk(){
  alert ('I can walk!');
  }
}

x.walk(); //'I can walk!'
x.fight(); //error
```

Then I decided to create a weapon class so that when this class is active, my Warriors in the game can fight. Some pseudocode how I imagine it:

```
class Weapon{

canFight(type:Warrior){
set warrior.fight=()=>{alert('I can fight!')};}

}

let x=new Warrior();

x.walk(); //'I can walk!'
x.fight() //'I can fight!'
```

So I need to extend the class itself and all its instances with the new methods and parameters when some sort of magic **extention** code is present. Thus I can incapsulate behaviour in the separate classes and extend it to other classes without need to have noticed them.

What I saw is mixins but the idea behind that is to explicit change my **Warrior** class to incapsulate new functions. I can't just say that since now my warriors can fight, I need to change the the cases when i use **Warriors** to some sort of new type - **FighterWarriors** and that can be a real pain if I need to quickly enchance the objects with the new behaviour.

This is working technique in c# and swift but I don't know about other languages.

So the questions are: how can I make this type of behaviour in Typescript? If can't, does the pure JS supports this? What can I read additionally for this theme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use interface merging and module augmentation to add members to a type. For the JS part, things are pretty simple you just need to add a new property on the `Warrior` prototype

```
// Warrior.ts
export class Warrior {

    constructor() { }

    walk() {
        alert('I can walk!');
    }
}
// Weapon.ts
import {Warrior } from './Warrior'

export class Weapon{
    canFight(type:Warrior){
    }
}

declare module './Warrior' {
    interface Warrior {
        fight(): void
    }
}
Warrior.prototype.fight = function (this: Warrior){
    console.log("FIGHT");
}

// Usage.ts

import {Warrior  } from './Warrior'
import './Weapon'


let x=new Warrior();
x.fight();
```

Comment: Thanks! One question, do you mean Warrior.ts or Weapon.ts in the second case? It seems it should be weapon.ts.

Comment: @gleb.kudr yeah, sorry my bad